# LVT lifting/shifting

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I have several sections of LVT (installed by a "professional") lifting/separating. Is there a way to fix this without redoing the entire floor?[image]

Comment: Is the adhesive releasing from the subfloor or the planks? Has there been moisture present (from above or below)? What _is_ the subfloor? Please [revise](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/284717/edit) to add detail about the situation, and take the [tour].

Comment: A "professional" gets paid for his work. It doesn't mean he's any good at it. Also, how old is the floor? After 15 or 20 years, this might not be unreasonable. Also, quality of laminate flooring has improved quite a bit over that time...

Comment: That has had water get under it and the subfloor is wood...OR...it is from an ultra bad installation job.

Comment: Or possibly no expansion gap at the edges and it's pushed itself up.